# Find rows with certain time deltas between them

Tags: sql, algorithm, time

Generally, my task is like that: there are a lot of ID's and timestamps for different actions. I heed to find those ID's where among

A1, A1, A2, A3, ..., An

exists Ai, Al, and Am (1 <= i,l,m <= n), that 1 hour<=timediff(Ai, Al)<=1 week and 1 hour<=timediff(Al, Am)<=1 week.
Here A means time of the action.

In particular, I have the data (like below) and want to find only those ID where following statement is true: same ID with at least 1 hour between 3 actions and no more than 1 week between them.

```
ID      EventDate
6727    2014-12-12 09:41:02.0
17390   2014-12-12 10:06:03.0
18179   2014-11-12 10:18:08.0
18179   2014-12-12 11:17:36.0
18179   2014-12-12 12:17:45.0
18179   2014-12-12 12:17:56.0
262070  2014-11-12 11:30:00.0
262070  2014-11-12 11:33:26.0
262070  2014-12-12 11:33:26.0
262070  2014-12-12 10:17:19.0
```

E.g., for that example it could be 18179 (as I could find 3 actions there: 10:06:03.0, 11:17:36.0, and 12:17:56.0) but not 262070 (as there are no 3 actions within 1-hour-to-1-week in log).

Could somebody help me do that in a most convenient SQL-way, but without stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried something like this

```
SELECT Start.ID FROM 
Table AS Start
INNER JOIN Table AS Middle ON  Start.ID = Middle.ID AND DATEDIFF( hour, Start.EventDate,Middle.EventDate) > 1 AND DATEDIFF( week , Start.EventDate,Middle.EventDate) < 1
INNER JOIN Table AS End ON  Start.ID = Middle.ID AND DATEDIFF( hour, End .EventDate,Middle.EventDate) > 1 AND DATEDIFF( week , End .EventDate,Middle.EventDate) < 1
WHERE Start.ID IS NOT NULL AND Middle.ID IS NOT NULL AND End .ID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Ask in comments, if something is not clear.

```
declare @example table (
    action_id int,
    action_date datetime
)

insert @example (action_id, action_date)
select 6727,    '2014-12-12 09:41:02.0' union all
select 17390,   '2014-12-12 10:06:03.0' union all
select 18179,   '2014-11-12 10:18:08.0' union all
select 18179,   '2014-12-12 10:17:36.0' union all
select 18179,   '2014-12-12 12:17:45.0' union all
select 18179,   '2014-12-12 11:17:26.0' union all
select 262070,  '2014-11-12 11:30:00.0' union all
select 262070,  '2014-11-12 11:33:26.0' union all
select 262070,  '2014-12-12 11:33:26.0' union all
select 262070,  '2014-12-12 10:17:19.0'

select distinct e.action_id
from (select action_id
        from @example
        group by action_id) e
    cross apply (select e1.action_date
                    from @example e1
                    where e1.action_id = e.action_id) ee1
    cross apply (select e2.action_date
                    from @example e2
                    where e2.action_id = e.action_id) ee2
    cross apply (select e3.action_date
                    from @example e3
                    where e3.action_id = e.action_id) ee3
where ee1.action_date<ee2.action_date and
        ee2.action_date<ee3.action_date and
        datediff(hour,ee1.action_date, ee3.action_date) between 1 and 24*7
group by e.action_id
```